# Laravel 4: Why can't I use aliases in my laravel code

Tags: laravel-4

Here's my code:

```
public function getReports()
        {   


            $reports=DB::table('reports')
            ->select(array('*',DB::raw('reports.id','reports.departmentID','reports.officerID','reports.created_at','reports.report','reports.title','department.name','posts.name AS pname')))
            ->leftjoin('department','reports.departmentID','=','department.id')
            ->leftjoin('posts','reports.postID','=','posts.id')             
            ->leftjoin('users','reports.officerID','=','users.id')
            ->leftjoin('events','events.id','=','reports.eventID')
            ->orderBy('reports.id','DESC')
            ->get();

            $reportsArray=array();
            foreach($reports as $row)
            {
                $reportsArray[]=array(
                    'id'=>$row->id,
                    'report'=>$row->report,
                    'title'=>$row->title,
                    'departmentName'=>$row->name,               
                    'created_at'=>$row->created_at,
                    'post'=>$row->pname,
                    );
            }

            return View::make('reports.reports')
            ->with('reports',$reportsArray);

        }
```

I'm getting the following error when I load the view: **Undefined property: stdClass::$pname**
This is basically a problem because i need to use aliases in many instances. And the error is basically the same when I try to use a column alias with any column. Can anyone see where the problem is with my code?

My Model:

```
class Report extends Eloquent
{
 protected $table = 'reports';  
protected $fillable= array(
'title','reportDate',,'departmentID','date','eventID','officerID','postID‌​',
);
 }
```

Comment: How does the actual model look like? What is the name of field in this case?

Comment: updated the question with the model.